# How to calculate modeline using cvt for 75hz without multiples of 60hz

Tags: linux, xorg, xrandr, modeline

I'm trying to see if my [LG 32UL500-W](https://www.rtings.com/monitor/reviews/lg/32ul500-w) monitor will overclock beyond 60hz. It looks like DisplayPort 1.2 [handles 4k at 75hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Resolution_and_refresh_frequency_limits).

When I run `xrandr --verbose`, it shows me the default VESA mode for 4k 60hz:

```
3840x2160 (0x5a) 533.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  3840 start 3888 end 3920 total 4000 skew    0 clock 133.31KHz
        v: height 2160 start 2214 end 2219 total 2222           clock  60.00Hz
```

This works fine. If I calculate it using `cvt 3840 2160 60 -r` I get the same values.

```
$ cvt 3840 2160 60 -r
# 3840x2160 59.97 Hz (CVT 8.29M9-R) hsync: 133.25 kHz; pclk: 533.00 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160R"  533.00  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsync
```

However, this command doesn't work if I try calculating the values for anything above 60hz.

```
$ cvt 3840 2160 75 -r

ERROR: Multiple of 60Hz refresh rate required for  reduced blanking.
```

If I run that same command without the reduced blanking flag, I get wildly different numbers that don't work when I add them to `xrandr` and apply them to a display.

```
$ cvt 3840 2160 60
# 3840x2160 59.98 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 134.18 kHz; pclk: 712.75 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync

$ cvt 3840 2160 75
# 3840x2160 74.95 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 169.16 kHz; pclk: 904.00 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_75.00"  904.00  3840 4168 4592 5344  2160 2163 2168 2257 -hsync +vsync
```

My monitor doesn't understand the signal if I try to apply those modes at either 60hz or 75hz.

Is there really no way to calculate an appropriate set of values for 75hz? I wish `cvt` would at least give me the option to calculate values for 75hz using `-r` so I could at least try them. I know 120hz is out of the question because DisplayPort 1.2 doesn't support that at 4k and there's no way my monitor will handle that rate. None of the online calculators seem to give me appropriate values either.

Comment: It's a 60Hz monitor - see https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-32UL500-W What makes you think you can "trick" it into being a 75Hz monitor & what possible benefit do you think it would have?

Comment: You can overclock monitors to run beyond their specs. The best way I know to do this on Linux is using `xrandr` to add new modes, but if there is a better way I would love to know. I just needed the correct modeline values, and CVT doesn't calculate them. I managed to get this working using the following guide: https://github.com/kevinlekiller/linux_intel_display_overclocking It works, but I don't know how big of an actual benefit it provides because it skips some frames. See my answer to this question for full details.

Comment: Note that most modern monitors don't actually support displaying random refresh rates even if you can get the monitor to sync. It might simply drop frames or duplicate frames if you run it with non-supported refresh rate. (High quality old school CRTs could run any refresh rate with any resolution but the panel technology is much less flexible.) If you can actually display more frames with overclocked signals, consider yourself lucky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVT 1.1 does not generate reduced blanking values for any rate other than 60 or a multiple of 60. You can use this [modified version of CVT](https://github.com/kevinlekiller/cvt_modeline_calculator_12) to generate those values anyway and push your monitor to its limits, but be careful running your monitor at rates higher than its spec. It could damage the monitor.

Follow this guide to download and compile CVT: https://github.com/kevinlekiller/linux_intel_display_overclocking

I tested this on my [LG 32UL500-W](https://www.rtings.com/monitor/reviews/lg/32ul500-w) and it actually works all the way up to 80hz, but not 85hz. It must be pushing DisplayPort 1.2 beyond its limits a bit.

Here are the mode values that my monitor accepted:

- `xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_65.00_rb2"  567.44  3840 3848 3880 3920  2160 2213 2221 2227 +hsync -vsync`
- `xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_70.00_rb2"  612.46  3840 3848 3880 3920  2160 2218 2226 2232 +hsync -vsync`
- `xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_75.00_rb2"  657.97  3840 3848 3880 3920  2160 2224 2232 2238 +hsync -vsync`
- `xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_80.00_rb2"  703.40  3840 3848 3880 3920  2160 2229 2237 2243 +hsync -vsync`

Add the mode that you want to use and set it for your monitor. For example, I used the following command to set 75hz:

1. `xrandr --newmode "3840x2160_75.00_rb2"  657.97  3840 3848 3880 3920  2160 2224 2232 2238 +hsync -vsync`
2. `xrandr --output DisplayPort-2 --mode 3840x2160_75.00_rb2 --rate 75`

I tested this at [testufo.com](https://testufo.com/mprt) in Chrome and it identified the higher refresh rate. The only problem is that it might be skipping a few frames, but that's a separate problem.

Comment: The test for frame skipping is [this](https://testufo.com/frameskipping) actually (and somehow you don't even need a high refresh rate camera like [here](https://testufo.com/scanout)). Btw 80-81Hz is indeed the limit of the HBR2 bandwidth with CVT-RBv2 timings in 4K, but if you feel really bold with them ([say](https://tomverbeure.github.io/video_timings_calculator), try an horizontal blanking interval of just 70 pixels) you might be able to pull off 85Hz too.

Comment: High speed camera is the best to verify the frames because using long exposure time might miss some errors. A single long exposure photo should be good enough to notice any skipped frames, though. Many LCD panels run at static framerate even though they can sync to other frequency signals, too. The result is typically skipped frames but the image looks otherwise okay so some people think they can overclock their displays this way.